# Como fazer um marquee sem a tag <marquee>?

Tags: javascript, html, css, css3

Estou precisando usar um *marquee*, mas como todos estão falando que *marquee* é uma coisa pré-histórica e não deve ser usado mais, estou em dúvida quanto ao que usar no lugar dele. No site da MDN fala isso:

> Essa funcionalidade é obsoleta. Embora ainda possa funcionar em alguns navegadores, seu uso é desencorajado, pois pode ser removido a qualquer momento. Tente evitar o uso.

Quais são minhas opções? Busco algo que seja o mais próximo possível de:

```
<marquee>Texto aqui</marquee>
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

De fato a tag `<marquee>` é [considerada obsoleta em HTML5](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/obsolete.html), pois é um elemento focado em comportamento e aparência, e não na estrutura do conteúdo. Por isso, recomenda-se que algo semelhante seja feito com CSS e/ou JavaScript.

Abaixo uma solução que usa somente CSS, baseada em [uma resposta em inglês](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21233577/825789). Note que o exemplo usa o [-prefix-free](http://leaverou.github.io/prefixfree/) para deixar o CSS mais limpo (trata-se de um JS que adiciona os prefixos para você, para que os recursos que dependem de prefixos, como `-webkit`, `-moz` e `-ms`, funcionem no maior número possível de *browsers*).

```css
.marquee {
  width: 100px;
  height: 22px;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 2px;
}
.marquee span {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: 100%;
  animation: marquee 15s linear infinite;
}
@keyframes marquee {
  0% {
    transform: translate(0, 0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate(-100%, 0);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="marquee"><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</span></div>
```

<sup>[Demonstração](http://jsfiddle.net/rL5cb/)</sup>

O funcionamento é bem simples:

- As regras em `.marquee` definem a aparência da caixa externa. Detalhe importante é o `white-space: nowrap;`, que mantém o conteúdo em uma única linha.
- As regras em `.marquee span` empurram o conteúdo todo para a direita (para que o marquee inicie vazio), e os parâmetros básicos da animação (chamada `marquee`), com duração de 15 segundos e repetição infinita.
- `@keyframes marquee` define dois quadros-chaves para a animação, um com o conteúdo na posição original, e o outro para o conteúdo totalmente deslocado para a esquerda, no fim da animação.

Comment: Sugestão: poderia trocar `translateX(x)` por `translate(x,y)`, assim poderia combinar com outros possíveis efeitos e ou combinações se necessário :)

Comment: Ué, mas já não tá?

Comment: eu fui editar o comentário e inverti a ordem, o correto seria: trocar  `translate(x,y)` por `translateX(x)`

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Deu preguiça de mudar, mas fica um +1 na sugestão.

Comment: Como faz para não ficar esse "buraco" quando o texto já foi quase todo processado?

Comment: @MichaelPacheco Aí é mais complicado, você precisa duplicar o conteúdo e fazer uma segunda animação, dando um efeito de loop infinito. Deve até dar pra fazer com CSS, mas complicado demais pra eu editar minha resposta... Uma opção também é fazer em JS, ou usar alguma biblioteca de carrossel.

Comment: @bfavaretto eu achei essa lib para Vue https://github.com/megasanjay/vue3-marquee

Answer (score 3):

Há algumas alternativas:

- Cross Browser marquee: http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex2/cmarquee.htm
- jScroller - Autoscroller para jQuery: http://jscroller.markusbordihn.de/
- Cross Browser Ticker/Marquee: http://javascript.about.com/od/effects/a/tick.htm
- jQuery plugins - Marquee: http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/plugin-tags/marquee

Fonte: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/326615/HTML-Marquee-its-alternatives

Comment: Ta doido, prefiro usar marquee doque usar 300 linhas pra uma coisa simples

Comment: @Josimara na verdade marquee e blink sempre foram muito desagradáveis, independente do número de linhas. A rejeição sempre foi trão grande por parte das pessoas, que provavelmente não fizeram um equivalente simples em CSS para desincentivar esse uso.

Answer (score -1):

Para imagens dei essa mudada.

```css
#slider{
    position: absolute;
    scroll-padding-bottom: 50px;
    right: 0;
    background: transparent;
    width: 150px;
    height: 50px;
    animation: anima 20s linear infinite;
 }
 
 @keyframes anima{
    from {right: 0}
    to {right: 100%}
 }
```

```html
<img src="img/well.jpg" id="slider" alt="Instalador de painel Solar">
```