# Como fazer um label com behavior="scroll"?

Tags: html5

Segue código:

```html
<marquee behavior="scroll" direction="left">Seu texto aqui</marquee>
```

Como eu posso fazer isso com label?

```
<label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label" for="Link">Seu texto aqui</label>
```

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Como fazer um marquee sem a tag <marquee>?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/11862/como-fazer-um-marquee-sem-a-tag-marquee)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode emular o comportamento da `<marquee>` (que hoje está indicada como deprecated), no CSS com `animation` e `translate()`.

```css
.marquee {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.marquee-scroll {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: 100%;
  animation: scroll 10s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes scroll {
  0% {
    transform: translate(0, 0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate(-100%, 0);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="marquee">
  <label for="Link" class="marquee-scroll">Seu texto aqui</label>
</div>
```