# Frase passando com JavaScript

Tags: javascript, animação, transição

Olá!
Sou totalmente leigo em JavaScript, mas estou com um projeto que preciso usar o JS em uma única situação e não estou conseguindo.

A página tem uma tabela que dentro de uma das células passa uma frase que vem do banco de dados, para não perder conteúdo de uma frase muito grande ou "estourar" os tamanhos da tabela e da página, preciso que essa frase fique passando da direita para a esquerda mostrando todo o conteúdo dela com javascript.

Alguém consegue me ajudar?

Comment: Code man, we need a code !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

É necessário apenas o uso do javascript? O **HTML** resolve isso pra você fácinho.

```html
<marquee>Essa frase ta andando, se liga...</marquee>
```

Comment: Relacionada (duplicata?): https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/11862/como-fazer-um-marquee-sem-a-tag-marquee

Comment: Opa Bsalvo! Assim realmente dá certo, eu achava que esse <marquee> havia sido descontinuado. Será que tem como eu alterar a velocidade que a frase passa?