# Fazer um texto com overflow-x: hidden se mover automaticamente

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap

Estou fixando o width do li e mandando todo o texto que exceder ficar hidden, agora gostaria de fazer com que a parte do texto que esta escondida se mexa automaticamente para aparecer na tela.

HTML:

```
ul
      - @realties.each do |realty|
        li.tabs
          a href="#tab-#{realty.id}" #{realty.address.street} , #{realty.address.number}
```

Css:

```
ul
  li
    width: 150px
    a
      overflow-x: hidden
      width: inherit
```

Resultado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Veja se é isso que precisa https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/11862/como-fazer-um-marquee-sem-a-tag-marquee

Comment: Ajudou bastante, consegui aplica, mas agora vem um outro problema, quero colocar a animação do movimento somente pros que estão ultrapassando o espaço permitido, e nao sei como fazer isso

Comment: Cara a forma mais fácil que conheço seria colocando uma classe para remover a animação nos textos que estiverem maior. Mas caso queira algo dinâmico vc vai precisar de um Script para contar quantos caracteres tem o texto e se ele vai colocar a animação ou não... ai ei não vou saber te ajudar. Mas vc pode fechar essa pergunta e abrir outra com esse problema, ou então Editar essa e colocar o código atual e perguntando do problema que tem agora.